# Python input() does not read whole input data

Tags: python, input, stdin

I'm trying to read the data from stdin, actually I'm using Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V to pass the values into cmd, but it stops the process at some point. It's always the same point. The input file is .in type, formating is that the first row is one number and next 3 rows contains the set of numbers separated with space. I'm using Python 3.9.9. Also this problem occurs with longer files (number of elements in sets > 10000), with short input everything is fine. It seems like the memory just run out. I had following aproach:

```
def readData():
# Read input
for line in range(5):
    x = list(map(int, input().rsplit()))
    if(line == 0):
        nodes_num = x[0]
    if(line == 1):
        masses_list = x
    if(line == 2):
        init_seq_list = x
    if(line == 3):
        fin_seq_list = x

return nodes_num, masses_list, init_seq_list, fin_seq_list
```

and the data which works:

```
6
2400 2000 1200 2400 1600 4000
1 4 5 3 6 2 
5 3 2 4 6 1
```

and the long input file:
https://pastebin.com/atAcygkk
it stops at the sequence: ... 2421 1139 322], so it's like a part of 4th row.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with `x` if `line > 3`.

Comment: yep, i've changed it to range(4), thanks

Comment: How are you sure that the problem is not created by your copy and paste? did you try to feed the stdin by another way?

Comment: A loop that does something (theoretically) different for each value of the loop index probably shouldn't be a loop in the first place.

Comment: Actually I have no idea how to pass it other way. The task requirement is to use "standard input", so I guess input(), so this copy paste is only way which I can think of

Comment: Ah, pasting in a large chunk of text is involves more than standard input. It is actually treated as typed text and goes through pty and may not be flow controlled.

Comment: Also, input() is primarily intended for user input. To use stdio, use the file streams instead.

Comment: `input` is really just a convenience wrapper around `sys.stdin.readline()`. While the latter returns `'\n'` for an empty line and `''` to indicate the end of the file, `input` returns `''` for an empty line and raises an exception at the end of the file. (`input` can also print a prompt to standard output, saving the user an explicit call to `print` or the like.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read input from "standard input", you just need to use the `stdin` stream. Since your data is all on lines you can just read until the EOL delimiter, not having to track lines yourself with some index number. This code will work when run as `python3.9 sowholeinput.py < atAcygkk.txt`, or `cat atAcygkk.txt|  python3.9 sowholeinput.py`.

```py
def read_data():
    stream = sys.stdin
    num = int(stream.readline())
    masses = [int(t) for t in stream.readline().split()]
    init_seq = [int(t) for t in stream.readline().split()]
    fin_seq = [int(t) for t in stream.readline().split()]
    return num, masses, init_seq, fin_seq
```

Interestingly, it does not work, as you describe, when pasting the text using the terminal cut-and-paste. This implies a limitation with that method, not Python itself.